# Injector returns undefined for $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I've been looking into unit testing a project I'm doing for Angular (my first). I've set up a DataTree service that depends on a NodeFactory and also makes $http calls.

First off, (a snippet of) my test:

```
describe("the data tree service", function() {

  let DataTree, NodeFactory, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('memApp.common'));

  beforeEach( inject(function(_DataTree_, _NodeFactory_, _$httpBackend_) {
      DataTree = _DataTree_;
      NodeFactory = _NodeFactory_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  describe("is sane, so it", function() {

      $httpBackend
        .when('GET', 'json/home.json')
        .respond(200, {
            "esv": {
                "_title" : "ESV",
                "_filePath" : "json/bookData.json"
            }
        });

      ...
  }
...
}
```

It is trying to set up a mock backend responding with JSON.

My Karma tests fail on the $httpBackend.when, specifically:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'when' of undefined
        at <the httpBackend.when call>
```

My DataTree service (a service service - just want one global instance of it):

```
(function() {
    angular.module('memApp.common')
        .service('DataTree', ['NodeFactory', '$http', '$q',    
    function(NodeFactory, $http, $q) {
    ...
    }]);
})();
```

My NodeFactory factory - a wrapper for a class:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('memApp.common')
        .factory('NodeFactory', function() {
    ....
    });
})();
```

Finally, my included karma.conf.js files:

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'js/common/common.module.js',     //memApp.common module def'd here
  'js/common/node.service.js',      //NodeFactory def'd here
  'js/common/datatree.service.js',  //DataTree def'd here
  'js/common/common.controller.js',
  'js/hierarchy/hierarchy.module.js',
  'js/hierarchy/hierarchy.controller.js',
  'js/rehearsal/rehearsal.module.js',
  'js/rehearsal/rehearsal.controller.js',
  'js/app/app.module.js',
  'js/hierarchy/hierarchy.directive.js',
  'js/rehearsal/rehearsal.directive.js',
  'spec/*Spec.js'                   //all Jasmine tests here - in particular, there is a test suite for NodeFactory here.
],
```

I don't think this is relevant, but NodeFactory's test does the following (and I have been burned by what other tests are doing before...):

```
describe("the Node service", function() {

    let NodeFactory;
    let home;

    beforeEach(module('memApp.common'));

    beforeEach( inject(function(_NodeFactory_) {
        NodeFactory = _NodeFactory_;
        home = NodeFactory.create();
    }));
    ...
});
```

I have gotten tests in my data tree service to pass without doing anything with $httpBackend. This sorta worries me as I think my service shouldn't be making actual $http calls in a unit test?

I am a bit of a newbie to ng-mock (and am taking the PluralSight course on said topic) but I'm trying to follow along with my project and this is blocking me from doing much. In general, $httpBackend still feels a tad magical.

Answer (score 2):

Well, heh...writing out my question sometimes goes a long way in answering it. (I spent a day looking at this, I swear.)

My call to $httpBackend wasn't contained in a test (just a describe block), so the beforeEach wasn't being called before it. I moved the code into an it...test, and the injection now works.